# How to create a 'startswith' function inside a class

Tags: c#, winforms, list, foreach, startswith

I'm working in List and storing my data in class and again using new list to differentiate between receive data.

> I'm using startswith function to check for data inside a string. But i also want to call **startswith** function inside loop with string is data form **class**. 
>   I can't add **startwith** because my **class** don't have definition for this function

Below is demo code help you understand what i'm asking

```
 class URLClass
{
    public URLClass()
    {

    }

    //packet count
    private int pktCount;
    public int PktCount
    {
        get { return pktCount; }
        set { pktCount = value; }
    }

    //URL accessed
    private string uRLString;
    public string URLString
    {
        get { return uRLString; }
        set { uRLString = value; }
    }}
```

**This is a class data...** I used a list for class data and name it **URLData**

Below code is the loop

```
foreach (var x in URLData) //URLData is list from above class
{
  if (x.StartsWith("SomeText")) // Here i face problem my class don't have any definition of Sartswith function is there any way i can define it manually
}
```

Comment: you need to make a "StartsWith" method in your class, and have it do it what you want to.

Comment: I think you might just want `x.URLString.StartsWith("SomeText")` but it's not completely clear.

Comment: What should start with this text? if URLString property should start you can use that method...x.URLString.StartsWith("SomeText")...

Comment: @FCin `StartsWith` is not an extension method.  It's just a regular method of `string`.

Comment: I think you just need to do "if (x.uRLString.Startswith("SomeText"))"

Comment: Yes but how can i use 'startswith' in class like how to create it's method?

Comment: @PaulGibson Yeah this is good.. But i need it to define in class

Comment: If you don't know how to create a method in a class, you need way more tutorials than we can help with.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify your URLClass to add the StartsWith method, you can still provide an *extension method* which may be equally useful.

```
public static class MyURLClassExtensions {
    public static bool StartsWith(this URLClass me, string text) {
        return me.URLString.StartsWith(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the method to the class:

```
class URLClass
{
    public URLClass()
    {

    }

    //packet count
    private int pktCount;
    public int PktCount
    {
        get { return pktCount; }
        set { pktCount = value; }
    }

    //URL accessed
    private string uRLString;
    public string URLString
    {
        get { return uRLString; }
        set { uRLString = value; }
    }}

    public bool StartsWith(string match)
    {
        return uRLString.StartsWith(match);
    }
```

**OR**

Use the string property in the loop:

```
foreach (var x in URLData) 
{
    if (x.URLString.StartsWith("SomeText"))
}
```

Either should work, and it's all pretty basic 101-level stuff.

You can also do this:

```
foreach (var x in URLData.Where(u => u.URLString.StartsWith("SomeText")))
{

}
```